# Typescript print Symbol \

Tags: html, typescript

I want to print the following: `\d`, the output on my html site is only `d`, how can you print the character `\`?

My code:

```
const regex1 = document.getElementById("regex1") as HTMLOutputElement;

regex1.textContent = "\d";
```

I tried escaping the character with ""\d"", but the output was ""d.

Comment: try escaping with "\\d"

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages, `\` acts as an escape character, so in order to type it, you have the escape it like so: `\\`. (`\\d` -> `\d`)